# Access Denied - Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm having a bit of a wierd problem.

At my company we use seperate admin accounts for all AD modification puposes (for eg. if my normal AD ID is User01 then my admin a/c wud be something like User01_adm -> this has the modification rights over ad users / groups). Now, i can make changes like say change the login script from ARS web console using my adm a/c but if i use the same in powershell script i get "Access denied" [System.UnauthorizedAccessException]. Is there a difference between the way these both are setup (web console & powershell console?)

I'm using below part for connecting to ARS server with my adm credentials:

```
 #Connect to ARS server
$GetCreds = Get-Credential -Credential $null
$ConnectARS = Connect-QADService -service $ArsServer -Proxy-Credential $GetCreds

 #make changes
$PopulateData = Set-QADUser -Identity $UserID -Credential $GetCreds -ObjectAttributes @{scriptPath=$LogonScr}
```

Can any1 pls point wht am i doing wrong?

Any help would be highly appreciated...

Comment: Any1, pretty please?

Comment: I have a similar problem to yours. I can change stuff with my admin account in ARS, with the GUI. But in PowerShell I can't do anything, it's like it's blocked..

Answer (score 0):

I've nowhere to try it, but shouldn't it be:

```
#Connect to ARS server
$GetCreds = Get-Credential -Credential $null
$ConnectARS = Connect-QADService -service $ArsServer -Credential $GetCreds

 #make changes
$PopulateData = Set-QADUser -Identity $UserID -Connection $ConnectARS -ObjectAttributes @{scriptPath=$LogonScr}
```

Comment: Tried it... unfortunately doesn't work. Same error :(

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it figured out, it was too simple:
it was mere  -Proxy switch missing in **Set-QADUser** statement
working fine now, thx all for help :)